# KMake PrawnPDF table cell do not break

Tags: ruby, prawn

How to make `prawnpdf` cell do not break?

```
require 'prawn'
require 'prawn/table'

t = [
  ['No.', 'Batch', 'Prog Session', 'Class Group', 'Subject', 'Lecturer', 'Coord. By', 'Room', 'Time', 'Merged', 'Capacity'],      
  ['1', 'LAW-2013', 'M', 'Class 1', 'MEDIA AND IT LAW', 'Muhammad Abdul Sholeh', '', '', '', 'Merged with another class', '40']
]

Prawn::Document.generate(OUTFILE, page_layout: :landscape) do
  text 'foo'
  font_size 9
  table t, header: true
end
```

[image: broken cell]

the 'LAW-2013' part is breaking, I need it in one line.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and tried it out, and for me the LAW-2013 part wasn't line breaking (all was displaying as I would expect).  Maybe it has to do with the versions of the Prawn gems you're using...? (I'm used prawn 2.0.1 and prawn-table 0.2.1 to generate the PDF, the latest versions at the time of this writing)

Comment: ah wait, my bad, i use shorter data on stackoverflow. The real data has long text on the 4th till the last cell columns on another rows